# Windows does not recognize folder, cygwin/linux does

Tags: windows, cygwin

Windows does not recognize a folder I have on my external hard drive, when i browse via cmd and use "ls" via **cygwin** i see the folder. using file explorer or using "dir" does not see the folder at all. plugging it into a version of linux, i see the folder just fine. the folder is not hidden, or should not be hidden.

any suggestions?

**Edit 2:** I can browse to the folder since i know what it is, i can't see it in win explorer or using `dir` in cmd

Comment: using cygwin i can use it just fine.. thanks i wasn't sure where this exactly goes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably have the system attribute set which may have copied over from the source via the command, You should just need to use the attrib command to reset the attributes of the folder:

```
attrib -S -H <Path of folder> /S
```

or

open folder options --->goto vew tab ---> uncheck hide protected operating system files. then you can view in explorer

```
if you want to view in command promt use "dir /a:s" instedof  "dir"
```

Comment: is there a linux command or a command i can use with cygwin, windows says it cant be found

Comment: its a Ms-Dos Command only. what operating system in windows you use?

Comment: yeah.. i figured..

Comment: did you find your folder

Comment: i know where and what the folder is, just can't use `dir` or win explorer to view the folder.
i could not use the attrib command to change anything

Comment: then do one thing open folder options --->goto vew tab  ---> uncheck hide protected operating system files. then you can view in explorer

Comment: That helped, so then i use the above to take off the system file-ness?

Comment: you can tick my answer if it is use full to you

Comment: although i still can't take off the system attribute on the folder (the contents are not system files). when i use the attribute command, it says that the folder can't be found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26276/discussion-between-civa-and-vnge)